# Javascript Filter array of object by array of objects cast type

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

need help on this one please. I have 2 arrays. 1st array is of my data and 2nd array is of the type to cast to. They are formatted like this:

```js
data = [
  {name:"Joe", age:36},
  {name:Mark, age:40}
];

types = [
  {column:"name", type:"String"},
  {column:"age", type:"Integer")
];
```

What I am trying to do is loop through data and set the appropriet type. Something like this:

```js
data.forEach((record) => {
    types.filter((f) => {
      f.column === record.label;
      if (f.type === 'String') {
        record.value = record.value.toString();
      else if (f.type === 'Integer') {
        record.value = parseInt(record.value)
      }
    );
```

I am way off...I know and thats why I am here asking. Above is just a simple explination.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: If you're only looking at strings or integers, why not just examine the property value, and convert it to an integer if it already looks like an integer? would that be a solution?

Comment: @AndrewParks - wish it were that easy. Client wants it like this

Comment: Is it only string vs integer? or are there other types possible?

Comment: @AndrewParks - there are many types i.e. DateTime, Decimal, Money, Integer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a more general code than what Andreyk provided, you might want to use something like this:

```
    let data = [{name:"Joe", age:36},{name:46, age:"40"}];
    
    let types = [{column:"name", type:"String"},{column:"age", type:"Integer"}];
    
    data.forEach(record => {
        //Extracts the keys. In the example Object.keys(record) = ['name', 'age']
        Object.keys(record).forEach(key => {
              // We then look for the type that corresponds to our key
              recordType = types.find(type => type.column === key);
            
              if (recordType) {
                  if (recordType.type === "String") {
                    record[key] = record[key].toString()
                  }
                  if (recordType.type === "Integer") {
                      record[key] = parseInt(record[key])
                  }
                  // Add you other types here
              } else {
                  //Deal with unexpected types here if you want to set a default one
              }
         })
    })
    //result [{ name: "Joe", age: 36 },{ name: "46", age: 40 }]
    console.log(data)
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can put your own custom transformation functions inside the `mapping` array.

```js
const data = [
  {name:'Joe', age:36, wealth: 4},
  {name:'Mark', age:'40', wealth: '$6.3'}
]

const types = [
  {column:'name',   type:'String'},
  {column:'age',    type:'Integer'},
  {column:'wealth', type:'Money'},
]

const mapping = {
  'String': String, 
  'Integer': parseInt, 
  'Number': Number, 
  'Money': x=>`$${(+String(x).replace(/[^\d.]/g,'')).toFixed(2)}`}

console.log(data.map(i=>Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(i)
  .map(([k,v])=>[k, mapping[types.find(({column:c})=>c===k).type](v)]))))
```

Comment: @pilchard thanks, good point. Bitwise can only handle 32-bit signed numbers

Answer (score -1):

The code you have provided has some errors in it. First of all, in the data array, the age values are not assigned as strings, but as numbers, which is correct. However, in your code, you are trying to convert them to strings using `record.value.toString()`. But in the data array, the values are stored as `record.age` and not `record.value`. Also, in the types array, the column property is misspelled as label. Finally, in the filter method, you are checking if `f.column === record.label`, but it should be `f.column === record.name` or `f.column === record.age`. Here's the corrected code:

```
data.forEach((record) => {
    types.filter((f) => {
        if (f.column === 'name') {
            if (f.type === 'String') {
                record.name = record.name.toString();
            }
        } else if (f.column === 'age') {
            if (f.type === 'Integer') {
                record.age = parseInt(record.age);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This code will loop through each record in the data array and then filter the types array to find a matching column. If a matching column is found, it will check the type and convert the value to the appropriate type.

Comment: I was actully looking for something more dynamic as this is a js function that will handle thousands of records and types. It needs to work for what ever data sets i pass to it.

Comment: @DSmith do you have custom types, other than javascript's string/number/bigint/boolean? In those cases, are you instantiating your own custom classes?

Comment: @AndrewParks - no custom classes or types. I get the types by fetching from database. Then what I am trying to do is make sure my data is the correct type before submitting.

Comment: @AndrewParks - this is all being done to large sets of data on an import routine. The records go through a lot of backend functions using SheetJS sheet_to_json etc. I just want to make sure types match to database before final submission.